# remove certain tag in files under linux?

Tags: linux, find

I found out that someone spyware on my server and the spyware infected all the files. Infected files have  tag at the bottom of the file.

is there a way to loop all the files and remove only certain tag under linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/tag//g' file*
```

or

```
sed -i '/tag/d' file*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to find files containing the tag, and then `sed` (or a `grep -v`) to remove it.